# How to get ListView visible items?

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create a windows 8 metro style app. I'm using a Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ListView object, how can I get either indexes of visible items or items themselves in list view (actually for all items visibility attribute is set to visible, but I need to get items which are currently shown and can be viewed on desktop), or at least to know if the certain ListViewItem is visible on the desktop now, or not?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: find the answer here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/22e96f78-2fb9-464a-af23-57a81a782a7d